# using load/get using generics

Tags: java, hibernate

With Hibernate, how do I load an entity using generics?

Curretly I am doing:

```
Entity e = (Entity) session.load(Entity.class, 123);
```

In NHibernate, with generics, I can do:

```
session.Get<Entity>(123);
```

What's the Hibernate equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't support [Reified Generics](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/11/reified-generics-for-java.html) *yet*.

Best what you could do is to wrap it in another convenience method to remove the need to cast:

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> cls, Long id) {
    return cls.cast(session.load(cls, id));
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```
Entity e = get(Entity.class, 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to BalusC's answer, you can be more explicit in the call to the generic wrapper method.  So, if the wrapper method is in a a class GenericSession:

```
public class GenericSession {

    private GenericSession() {}

    public static <T> T get(Class<T> cls, Long id) {
        return cls.cast(session.load(cls, id));
    }
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
Entity e = GenericSession.<Entity>get(Entity.class, 123);
```

This should give you a better idea of how things are cast.

Comment: This implies a `static` session. You don't want to have that.

Comment: True.  I was treating the method as a function, which would mean adding the session as a parameter: public static <T> get(Session session, Class<T> cls, Long id);

Comment: Actually you dont need the '<Entity>' in the method call.

Comment: You shouldn't need it, but some compilers will complain if you don't put it there.